# Smooth movement of Pick and drop robot with stepper motor

Tags: c++, robotics, firmware, stepper, nucleo

I am building a pick and drop robot which has 3 stepper motors. I am using NUCLEO-F746ZG microcontroller and C++ programming to control it.

Now the problem is the arm moves with jerks in start and end (inertia) and I want to smooth the movement. For that I want to accelerate while the motor starts and decelerate when the motor stops. I tried different methods but none was working, the motor was moving in constant speed only. Kindly help me with this problem to make stepper motor move smoothly.

```c++
#include "stepperMotor.h"
#include "mbed.h"

int motorSpeed; // stepper speed
const float acc = 100;
int mspeed;

sMotor::sMotor(PinName A0, PinName A1, PinName A2, PinName A3) : _A0(A0), _A1(A1), _A2(A2), _A3(A3)
{ // Defenition of motor pins
    _A0 = 0;
    _A1 = 0;
    _A2 = 0;
    _A3 = 0;
}

void sMotor::anticlockwise(int mspeed)
{ // rotate the motor 1 step anticlockwise 
     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        switch (i)
        { // activate the ports A0, A2, A3, A3 in a binary sequence for steps
            case 0:
            {
                _A0 = 0;
                _A1 = 0;
                _A2 = 1;
                _A3 = 0;
            }
            break;

            case 1:
            {
                _A0 = 0;
                _A1 = 0;
                _A2 = 0;
                _A3 = 0;
            }
            break;

            case 2:
            {
                _A0 = 0;
                _A1 = 0;
                _A2 = 0;
                _A3 = 1;
            }
            break;

            case 3:
            {
                _A0 = 0;
                _A1 = 1;
                _A2 = 0;
                _A3 = 1;
            }
            break;

            case 4:
            {
                _A0 = 0;
                _A1 = 1;
                _A2 = 1;
                _A3 = 1;
            }
            break;

            case 5:
            {
                _A0 = 1;
                _A1 = 1;
                _A2 = 1;
                _A3 = 1;
            }
            break;

            case 6:
            {
                _A0 = 1;
                _A1 = 0;
                _A2 = 1;
                _A3 = 1;
            }
            break;

            case 7:
            {
                _A0 = 1;
                _A1 = 0;
                _A2 = 1;
                _A3 = 0;
            }
            break;
        }

        wait_us(mspeed);
      // wait_us(motorSpeed); // wait time defines the speed 
        
    }
}

void sMotor::clockwise(int mspeed)
{ // rotate the motor 1 step clockwise 
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                _A0 = 0;
                _A1 = 0;
                _A2 = 0;
                _A3 = 1;
            }
            break;

            case 1:
            {
                _A0 = 0;
                _A1 = 0;
                _A2 = 1;
                _A3 = 1;
            }
            break;

            case 2:
            {
                _A0 = 0;
                _A1 = 0;
                _A2 = 1;
                _A3 = 0;
            }
            break;

            case 3:
            {
                _A0 = 0;
                _A1 = 1;
                _A2 = 1;
                _A3 = 0;
            }
            break;

            case 4:
            {
                _A0 = 0;
                _A1 = 1;
                _A2 = 0;
                _A3 = 0;
            }
            break;

            case 5:
            {
                _A0 = 1;
                _A1 = 1;
                _A2 = 0;
                _A3 = 0;
            }
            break;

            case 6:
            {
                _A0 = 1;
                _A1 = 0;
                _A2 = 0;
                _A3 = 0;
            }
            break;

            case 7:
            {
                _A0 = 1;
                _A1 = 0;
                _A2 = 0;
                _A3 = 1;
            }
            break;
        }
        wait_us(mspeed);
    }
}

void sMotor::step(int num_steps, int direction, int speed)
{// steper function: number of steps, direction (0- right, 1- left), speed (default 1200)
    int count = 0; // initalize step count
    float stepTime = 1.0 / speed;  //aTry
    int w = num_steps;
    mspeed = 250;
    int speedMultiplier = 10;
    
    motorSpeed = speed; //set motor speed
    if (direction == 0) // turn clockwise
        do
        {
            clockwise(mspeed);
            count++;

            for (int i = 0; i < (w/4); i++)
            {
                while (mspeed != speed)
                {
                    mspeed = mspeed - speedMultiplier;
                } 
            }
            for (int i = w/4; i < 3 * (w / 4); i++)
            {
                mspeed = speed; 
            }            
            for (int i = 3 * (w / 4); i < w; i++)
            {
                while (mspeed != 400)
                {
                    mspeed = mspeed + speedMultiplier;
                }
            }
        } while (count < num_steps); // turn number of steps applied 
        
    else if (direction == 1) // turn anticlockwise
    { 
        count = 0;
        do
        {
            anticlockwise(mspeed);
            count++;      

            for (int i = 0; i < (w / 4); i++)
            {
                while (mspeed != speed)
                {
                    mspeed = mspeed - speedMultiplier;
                } 
            }
            for (int i = w/4; i < 3 * (w / 4); i++)
            {
                mspeed = speed; 
            }            
            for (int i = 3 * (w / 4); i < w; i++)
            {
                while (mspeed != 400)
                {
                    mspeed = mspeed + speedMultiplier;
                }
            }
        } while (count < num_steps);// turn number of steps applied 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note - the usual way to calculate a smooth trajectory is to use a power of 5 polynomial function. It's easy to find polynomial coefficients for such a function with constraints that velocity and acceleration are 0 at the end points of the trajectory and maximum in the middle point.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few possible improvements in your code: you have a field `mspeed` and you have a parameter `mspeed` in two methods - the parameter overrides the field. But as you implemented it now, the parameter wouldn't be necessary at all, because the methods `clockwise` and `anticlockwise` can access the field `mspeed`.

Also you assign the field `motorspeed` but you never use it.

The name of the field and parameters `mspeed` is misleading, usually a movement is faster with a higher speed, but you use it as waiting time, so `delay` would be a better name.

For the `clockwise` and `anticlockwise` methods: are you sure that you use the correct values and the correct order to activate the coils of the stepper motor? To my understanding it should be possible that you have a list of values for a full step and you can "play" it in one direction for clockwise and in the opposite direction for counter-clockwise motion. This way you would not have to use a `switch` statement and also only one method for both directions.

In the method `step` you should use a better name for `w`, maybe `position`?
Also in that method you have a huge code block for clockwise and anticlockwise movement that is completely equal, just the call to the `clockwise` and `anticlockwise` methods differ. To prevent code duplication errors, you should move that outer `if` further inside so that it just decides the actual call to one of the two methods. This is the most important improvement as it has impact on the fix if your problem!

To your actual problem:
In your `step` method you use three `for` loops to decrease the delay (speed) from a position of 0 to 1/4 of the target position, the keep it still from 1/4 to the 3/4 of the target position and finally increase the delay again from 3/4 to the complete target position.
Inside the acceleration and deceleration `for` loops you have a `while` loop.
And all of these nested loops are contained in one outer `do`-`while` loop for the stepping.

**BUT**: you only need the outer `do`-`while` loop. The inner loops are run for each step, so the delay is accelerated, kept constant and decelerated for every step of the motor.
What you should have instead is a nested `if` inside that outermost loop that decides for each cycle:

- if `count` is in the first quarter of the target range (`num_steps`), do the acceleration
- else if `count` is in the last quarter of the target range, do the deceleration
- else use the delay that was given into the `step` method.

Please note that for an even smoother movement, you have to process acceleration and deceleration also inside your method(s) to move the motor one full step, because actually you execute the same delay 8 times for a step, but you could vary it there as well!

Here some code for the `step` method - please note that my C++ knowledge was unused for several years and I also wasn't able to test this code, so I don't know if it even compiles. Feel free to fix it where necessary ;-)

```c++
void sMotor::step(int num_steps, int direction, int delay)
{// stepper function: number of steps, direction (0- right, 1- left), waiting time (default 1200)
    int speedMultiplier = 10; 

    // ensure that input delay param is used for the largest part.
    mspeed = delay + speedMultiplier * num_steps / 4;

    for (int step = 0; step < num_steps; ++step)
    {
        if (step < (num_steps / 4))
        {
            mspeed -= speedMultiplier;
        }
        else if (step > (3 * (num_steps / 4)))
        {
            mspeed += speedMultiplier;
        }
        else
        {
            mspeed = delay;
        }

        if (direction == 0)
        {
            clockwise(mspeed);
        }
        else if (direction == 1)
        {
            anticlockwise(mspeed);
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't use acceleration and deceleration "inbetween" the steps, so that optimization is left up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help can you help me more to update the code with acceleration and deceleration. My final goal is to smooth the movement.

Comment: I hope that my snippet helps you, but I didn't cover all possible improvements as I lack the ability to test it.